# ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs not found on calling API help page

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]When I Uncomment this line for api documentation

```
//// Uncomment the following to use the documentation from XML documentation file.
     config.SetDocumentationProvider(new  XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/BitCoinWrapperAPI.xml")));
```

I received an error :

`An exception of type 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll but was not handled in user code`

`Additional information: Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type HelpController, key ""`

When I call the `Index` page in the `HelpController` of the API, anybody knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I added this line and it works without exception

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.SelectConstructor(() => new HelpController()));
```